# Why is this XSS not working on my site?

Tags: xss

I'm attempting to make a site with an example of what XSS would look like, so in this I take user input and set a paragraph element's innerHTML to the user input but the script isn't running. However the script tag is present within the span. Anyone know why?

input in text box: `<script>alert()</script>`

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>XSS example</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <input type="text" id="inputBox"/>
    <button id="displayButton">submit</button>
    <span id="inputDisplay"></span>
        
    <script>
        const textInput = document.getElementById("inputBox");
        const inputDisplay = document.getElementById("inputDisplay");
        const displayButton = document.getElementById("displayButton");

        displayButton.onclick = event => {
            inputDisplay.innerHTML = textInput.value;
            textInput.value = "";
        }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: However, if you input: <img src="xx" onerror="alert('xss attack')" />  ....

Comment: Not exactly sure why, but if you do "document.write(textInput.value)" your script injection of (<script>alert()</script>) works.  Maybe because it's blasting the whole page it causes execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine.
Whatever you put inside is what makes the trick

```
<script><img title="</script><img src onerror=alert(1)>"></script>
```

P.S!
It relays on your Webrowser. Use [this](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/cheat-sheet) as a refrence